Created a component lib with React and js, but when i wan to use the library i get: The requested module does not provide an export
I have created a simple component library in React with Javascript. The intention is that I can use it locally. So I called a button I created my library(just a simple button). But I keep getting the following error message in the console: ```App.jsx:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/C:/Users/davym/Documents/HetDomeinUI/dist/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at App.jsx:5:8)`. Did I probably put something wrong in my package.json in the library?
BasicButton.js:

class BasicButton extends Component {
  render() {
    const { label } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <button>{label}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BasicButton;

Index.js:

export { BasicButton } from "./components/BasicButton";

package.json:

{
  "name": "hetdomeinui",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "description": "Reusable components",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.js"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "watch": "babel src --out-dir dist --watch",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "component",
    "npm"
  ],
  "author": "Your Name",
  "license": "MIT",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^19.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^19.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.26.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.26.3"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
}


Could you please edit your question to format code properly? And please do not upload images of code/data/errors..

The reason the editor told you to add code, which you worked around by adding those useless 'enter code here' messages, is because the question should contain ALL the relevant code as text, not images. Please read the How to ask a question guide, then edit your question to follow it

I hope now this is better and more clear
